# Why does Linux not detect the motherboard wifi unless the system is first booted into Windows?

Tags: wifi

I have a dual boot system, and if I select Linux after powering up the computer, usually it will not detect the built-in motherboard wifi. So what I have to do is restart and go into Windows, where it will always detect the wifi card. Then I have to restart again so I can boot into Linux and the wifi card is detected.

Why does this happen? It seems like Windows does something automatically to power on the wifi which causes Linux to be able to detect it.

Here are some tests I ran when wifi wasn't detected.

dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn

```
tsc: Unable to calibrate against PIT
  #9 #10 #11 #12 #13 #14 #15
platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
acpi PNP0C14:01: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
rcraid: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
rcraid: module license 'Proprietary' taints kernel.
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
<5>AMD, Inc. rcraid raid driver version 8.1.0 build_number 8.1.0-00039 built Jun 07 2022
<5>rcraid built on dudeshouse by root on Tue 07 Jun 2022 02:22:10 PM PDT
<5>rcraid: cmd_q_depth 512, tag_q_depth 16, max_xfer 448, use_swl 0xffffffff
ata2.00: LPM support broken, forcing max_power
ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata4.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata4.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
ata4.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata4.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
ata2.00: LPM support broken, forcing max_power
ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata2.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying PIO
sda: p1 size 234441648 extends beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
sda: p1 size 234441648 extends beyond EOD, truncated
sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
usb 3-6: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 2 but max is 1
usb 3-6: config 1 has no interface number 1
kvm: no hardware support
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110
usb 3-4.1: 1:1: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x3
usb 3-4.1: 2:1: cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x83
kvm: already loaded the other module

NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  470.129.06  Thu May 12 22:52:02 UTC 2022
nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc01 tx timeout
Bluetooth: hci0: FW download error recovery failed (-110)
kauditd_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
Bluetooth: hci0: MSFT filter_enable is already on
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a80a
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Switch Upstream
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
03:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
03:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
03:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
05:00.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
06:00.0 RAID bus controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 7916 (rev 51)
07:00.0 RAID bus controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 7916 (rev 51)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2216 (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
0a:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
0a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
0a:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

lsusb

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0bc2:331a Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Desk
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0b05:18f3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 047f:02e8 Plantronics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:4010 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 25a7:fa23 Compx 2.4G Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:0209 Razer USA, Ltd BlackWidow Tournament Edition Chroma
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

rfkill

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

When the card is detected it looks like this.

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

The output of lspci doesn't change.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` + `lspci` + `lsusb` + `rfkill` after cold booting straight into Linux.

Comment: Also please check whether this is reproducible under kernel 5.18.3.

Comment: Isn't this a case where you do not have the required firmware in lilnux?

Comment: It doesn't look like missing firmware because then it would always fail to find the wifi but it finds it if Windows runs first.